# Why sorting on tablesorter column remove the horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

Im just using the sample from the **[plugin](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-scroller.html)**.

When the table load from my ajax has one horizontal scroll but as soon I click on the ID column to sort the scroll disapear and the columns width become adjusted to cell content.

[image]

I like the second behaviour better. So how I do so my Table start like that from begining?

Also  there is a way `DateTime` Text doesnt split?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [`widthFixed` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widthfixed) to `true` will "lock in" the width of the column using a `<col>` with a defined percentage width. So that should prevent the table from resizing after an update.

If that doesn't help, then use some css to prevent text wrapping:

```
.tablesorter tr td:nth-child(2) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: But any idea why the click on sort adjust the width? I would like to execute a javascript so the table start that way.